# How to pass function to html

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue js, so I have simple function to hide the progress bar created in methods, but doesn't seem to work, I'm wondering if I need to add event or bind it, I think it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

```js
methods: {
    hideProgressBar: function() {
      const hideProgress = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");

      if (hideProgress) {
        hideProgress.classList.add(hide);
      } else {
        hideProgress.classList.remove(hide);
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f5a623;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.hide.progress-bar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke the method when the page is loaded, add the following created option after your methods option

```
created: function(){
    this.hideProgressBar()
  }
```

otherwise if you want to invoke the method based on an event then you would need to add your event.

Answer (score 0):

just try like this:

```
methods: {
  hideProgressBar: function() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0];
    if (element.classList.contains('hide')) {
      element.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      element.classList.add('hide');    
    }    
  }
}


<div class="progress-bar">
  Progress bar 1  div
</div>

<div class="progress-bar hide">
  Progress bar 2 div
</div>
```

I have used two progress bar for demonstration. Initially,

The first progress bar doesn't contain the hide class so hide class will be added.

Then the second progress already has hide class so it will be removed

DEMO:

```js
//hides first progress bar by adding hide class.
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0];
  if (element.classList.contains('hide')) {
    element.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    element.classList.add('hide');

  }


 //display second progress bar by remove hide class
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[1];
  if (element.classList.contains('hide')) {
    element.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    element.classList.add('hide');

  }
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f5a623;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.hide.progress-bar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  Progress bar 1  div
</div>

<div class="progress-bar hide">
  Progress bar 2 div
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however as a sample code, it shouldn't have click event or button, the progress bar is suppose to be hidden automatically

Comment: @Udzzzz now check out my answer I have removed button now the progress bar is automatically hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `vue.js` you'd want to use the inbuilt directives as much as you can.
This means you can avoid the whole `hideProgressBar` method.

```
<button @click="hideProgressBar = !hideProgressBar">Try it</button>
<div class="progress-bar" v-if="!hideProgressBar">
  Progress bar div
</div>
```

And you script would have a `data` prop that would help you toggle the hide/show of the progress bar

```
data () {
   return {
      hideProgressBar: false
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however as a sample code, it shouldn't have click event or button, the progress bar is suppose to be hidden automatically